# How to use available browser fonts in a Flutter web app

Tags: flutter, fonts

I'd like to use fonts that are available in the browser, like all the standard font families. But specifying the font family isn't changing my fonts.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'flutter web app',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        textTheme: TextTheme(bodyText2: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Courier New'))

      ),
      home: HomeView(),
    );
  }
}
```

How do I use available fonts without having to download and add the fonts to the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google font package

https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts

Comment: Thank you. The package is perfect and easy to use.